# Cloudflare with Magento 2 admin page issues

Tags: magento2

I have configured a Magento 2.0.5 website with Cloudflare. The issue is some admin pages are not loading correctly. For example, catalog management page cannot load products list, user management page cannot load user list. Other admin pages work OK. It seems related to XHR queries used in those pages. But I checked those XHR queries, all returned correct responses.

I can only get those pages working by enabling Cloudflare development mode. I also configured Cloudflare Page Rules to by pass cache for admin pages, but it doesn't work.

Anyone has encountered the same issue before?

Answer (score 3):

Please ensure that RocketLoader, auto-minify and Mirage is turned off.

You can [find CoudFlare's performance settings in the speed tab](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168206-How-do-I-access-my-CloudFlare-Performance-Settings-) of your Dashboard:

[image: Performance Settings in CloudFlare]

In order to improve performance, I'd highly suggest you [enable HTTP/2](https://www.cloudflare.com/http2/), this will give you many of the performance benefits which RocketLoader would traditionally offer and more.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue, and it was related specifically to auto minify of HTML.

Using Mirage didn't create any problem for our case (Magento 2.0.7), neither in admin or front end.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is disable CloudFlare performance improvements for Magento 2 backend and keep it enabled for frontend.

CloudFlare -> PageRules -> Add Magento 2 admin URL and select "Disable performance rule"